# Multisig one to many transaction

Tags: multisig

Is it possible to sign one to many transaction in multisig 2/2 wallet?
I want functionality where both sides can sign transaction that split the wallet without a need to create gap that requires a trust where one part will be sent to A in person A favor but B will not be sent in person B favor because person A will not want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like multisig works as a normal wallet so same as with a regular one you use the same command for it and then add following addresses and amounts you need. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean sending to two destinations in one transaction. If so, that's possible, just give two address+amount pairs in the transfer command, eg:

transfer 4xxxxx 5 4yyyyyyyy 2

The fact that the wallet is multisig does not have any impact on the ability to do this.